# How to set background color for BottomBar?

Tags: android, bottombar

I using [this](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) library for using `BottomBar` in my app and I can't set background color for this `BottomBar`.

My code:

```
 mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(parent.findViewById(R.id.content), savedInstanceState);
    mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottombar_menu, new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {

        }
    });

    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent));
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(1, ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent));
```

My BottomBar background color is white - I want set BootomBar like:
[image]

**UPD 1** I tried this code:

```
mBottomBar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

But this change background on my content (Look to Content for nearby in screenshot), doesn't in `BottomBar`

Comment: The `BottomBar` you are using is just `FrameLayout`, you can use `setBackgroundColor(color)` or `setBackground(Drawable)` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this. It works for me

```
mBottomBar.getBar().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent));
```

Comment: @dwinnbrown Great. I think It shows deprecated in this line getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent). I have updated the code. Now I believe it will resolve your deprecated.

Comment: I believe that yes that will work however it gives me an error `cannot get method 'getActivity()'` - could be because I didn't update the gradle file?

Comment: If your BottomBar in fragment, use getActivity() else in Activity then use
YourActivity.this

Comment: I am using fragments but am trying to set this in the main activity file.

Comment: You don't know how to solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349897/how-to-set-inactive-tab-colour-for-bottombar by any chance?

Comment: I recommend using it on your activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117200/discussion-between-dwinnbrown-and-masum).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, I tried something else. When you change the background for each you have it does work. I added this line for every tab I have:

```
bottomBar.getTabAtPosition(0).setBackgroundColor(backgroundColorInt);
```