# How to set inactive tab colour for BottomBar

Tags: java, android, android-tabs, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to set the colour for the inactive tabs on BottomBar but can't find any method for doing so. I have set the background colour for the bar using this: 
`mBottomBar.getBar().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));`

and would like to set the tabs to appear as white even when not in use, however don't seem to be able to do it:
I am trying this method, but it doesn't work:

```
mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, "#ffffff");
```

on all the four tabs e.g. `.mapColorForTab(1, "#ffffff"#);` etc.

Comment: Have you checked [this issue](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/issues/205). It mentions about overriding `bb_inActiveBottomBarItemColor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the backgroundcolor of a specific tab by using the following line:

```
bottomBar.getTabAtPosition(0).setBackgroundColor(backgroundColorInt);
```

When you use this line multiple times for each tab, you can change the backgroundcolor of the whole tab.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `darkMode` function solved this. Simply set in `MainActivity.java` like so:

```
mBottomBar.useDarkTheme();
```